# Speed of property dictionary slower than using a switch statement

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

I currently have a class 'ArisingViewModel' that has around 20-30 properties on it that will be checked 10,000+ times when I am generating various data.

Initially I had a method to retrieve the arising property values from an XML string along the lines of:

```
    public object GetArisingPropertyValue(string propertyName)
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "name_1":
                return Name1;
            case "another_name":
                return AnotherName;

            // etc.
        }
    }
```

But this was  adapted to use a property dictionary in order to make things easier to update and make life easier with respect to other parts of the project. So I set up my property dictionary like so:

```
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> PropertyMap;


    static ArisingViewModel()
    {
        PropertyMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var myType = typeof(ArisingViewModel);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (propertyInfo.GetGetMethod() != null)
            {
                var attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<FieldNameAttribute>();

                if (attr == null)
                    continue;

                PropertyMap.Add(attr.FieldName, propertyInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

I apply attributes to any relevant propertys like so:

```
    [FieldName("name_1")]
    public string Name1
    {
        get
        {
            return _arisingRecord.Name1;
        }
    }
```

And then find property names/values using the following methods:

```
    public static string GetPropertyMap(string groupingField)
    {
        string propName;
        PropertyMap.TryGetValue(groupingField, out propName);
        return propName; //will return null in case map not found.
    }

    public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

My issue is, that I'm finding that processing is a significant amount quicker using the old switch statement (using a very simple timer class to measure how long the system is taking - ~20 seconds vs ~25 seconds).

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, or any ways to improve the current code?

Comment: Put *property*, not *property name* into the dictionary

Comment: Reflection **is slow** (here even property searching is repeated for each access). If in this case is an issue just build a dictionary of delegates (instead of property names): Dictionary<string, Delegate>. Delegate invocation is slower than your first method (if number of properties isn't huge) but nothing so noticeable. You may also experiment with Expressions and Reflection.Emit but...well measure first!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to me. I'll have a look into a Dictionary<string, delegate> solution and see how quick that is, and if it's still slow it's back to the switch!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing a class similar to [`ObjectModelAdaptor`](https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/blob/master/Antlr4.StringTemplate/Misc/ObjectModelAdaptor.cs) from the C# port of StringTemplate 4 (BSD 3-clause license). This functionality is heavily used in performance-critical sections of the template rendering pipeline, and profiling indicates that the current implementation performs quite well.

This class uses a reasonably efficient caching and dispatch mechanism, though it could be improved for .NET 4+ users by using `ConcurrentDictionary` and removing the `lock` statements.

You'll likely want to change out the implementation of `FindMember` to implement the logic specific to your properties with attributes.